# Need to display a notification in my iOS application when there is new update (latest version) available in app store

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to display a notification in my iOS Application when there is a new update available in app store, when I click the notification I need to redirect user to the my app page in itunes.apple.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging). Its a 3rd party server that helps you send push notifications to the devices. The tutorial is available [here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/iOS+Tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use third party with servers integration like [Xtify](http://www.xtify.com/) or the french solution [Mainline](http://mainline.fr)